# At exactly what point of execution are merge fields in EmailMessage resolved?

Tags: email, emailmessage, order-of-execution, merge-field

I want to create a custom logic that will copy the value of `EmailMessage.Subject` after the merge fields used in it get resolved.

I tried to do it on the `after insert` trigger on `EmailMessage` object. However, it turns out that the merge fields used in Subject field are not always resolved before `after insert` trigger execution. Is it a normal behavior? Should I use a flow for this case instead?

**Lightning Email Template configuration**:
[image]

**Here is how the email is send using Case.SendEmail action**:
[image]

**Here is the received email** (don't look at the yellow part as it is automatically appended to email subject in the `after insert` trigger, it's not a merge field that is used in the email):
[image]

**What I want to achieve?**
I want to save in some field on the Case object the latest email subject which is related to this case.

Comment: Can you show evidence that merge fields in Subject are not resolved at `afterInsert` but are resolved in the body? Are you sure the merge fields are properly formed?

Comment: @cropredy I've just added photos. Merge fields are properly formed but it also turns out that these merge fields are not resolved also in the body.

Comment: As I said, in the `after insert` trigger the email subject contains merge fields but they are not resolved yet, and the custom logic used there makes such an assignment:

`case.Customer_s_Latest_Email_Subject__c` = `emailThatFiredTrigger.Subject`

Comment: related: https://www.salesforceben.com/your-complete-guide-to-salesforce-lightning-email-templates/ - note statement that cross-object merge fields are not supported

Comment: @cropredy where am I using the crossobject merge field?

Comment: ah, my bad -- I see that the template is based on Case .  I'll need to do some more research. Perhaps someone else on welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. can step in with an idea

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the solution for this scenario. I've created the Record-Triggered Flow on EmailMessage object that is ran everytime the EmailMessage is inserted and it's `Status` is equal to `Sent`. This is propably the best way to copy a value from a certain EmailMessage field in which the Merge Fields were used.